# Understanding what goes on with textarea selection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea, selection

I am working on an in-browser editor within a `textarea`.  I have started looking for some information on dealing with `textarea` selection and found [this jQuery plugin, fieldSelection](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection) that does some simple manipulation.

However, it doesn't explain what's going on.

I want to understand more on textarea selection in JavaScript, preferably with a description of both pre-DOM3 and post-DOM30 scenarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with PPK's [introduction to ranges](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html). Mozilla developer connection has info on [W3C selections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection). Microsoft have their system [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(VS.85).aspx). Some more tricks can be found [in the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selection+javascript).

In addition to incompatible interfaces you'll be happy to know that there is extra bizarreness going on with `textarea` nodes. If I remember correctly they behave as any other nodes when you select them in IE, but in other browsers they have an independent selection range which is exposed via the `.selectionEnd` and `.selectionStart` properties on the node.

Additionally, you should really take a look at `.contentEditable` as a means to edit things live. From the release of Firefox3, this is now supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thanks Borgar!  I've never heard of contentEditable before.  I will be getting familiar with it post haste!

Comment: Please note that the name is `.contentEditable` not `.contentEdiable` (minor typo that I cannot edit)

Answer (score 31):

```
function get_selection(the_id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(the_id);

    //Mozilla and DOM 3.0
    if('selectionStart' in e)
    {
        var l = e.selectionEnd - e.selectionStart;
        return { start: e.selectionStart, end: e.selectionEnd, length: l, text: e.value.substr(e.selectionStart, l) };
    }
    //IE
    else if(document.selection)
    {
        e.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        var tr = e.createTextRange();
        var tr2 = tr.duplicate();
        tr2.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        tr.setEndPoint('EndToStart',tr2);
        if (r == null || tr == null) return { start: e.value.length, end: e.value.length, length: 0, text: '' };
        var text_part = r.text.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.'); //for some reason IE doesn't always count the \n and \r in the length
        var text_whole = e.value.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.');
        var the_start = text_whole.indexOf(text_part,tr.text.length);
        return { start: the_start, end: the_start + text_part.length, length: text_part.length, text: r.text };
    }
    //Browser not supported
    else return { start: e.value.length, end: e.value.length, length: 0, text: '' };
}

function replace_selection(the_id,replace_str)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(the_id);
    selection = get_selection(the_id);
    var start_pos = selection.start;
    var end_pos = start_pos + replace_str.length;
    e.value = e.value.substr(0, start_pos) + replace_str + e.value.substr(selection.end, e.value.length);
    set_selection(the_id,start_pos,end_pos);
    return {start: start_pos, end: end_pos, length: replace_str.length, text: replace_str};
}

function set_selection(the_id,start_pos,end_pos)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(the_id);

    //Mozilla and DOM 3.0
    if('selectionStart' in e)
    {
        e.focus();
        e.selectionStart = start_pos;
        e.selectionEnd = end_pos;
    }
    //IE
    else if(document.selection)
    {
        e.focus();
        var tr = e.createTextRange();

        //Fix IE from counting the newline characters as two seperate characters
        var stop_it = start_pos;
        for (i=0; i < stop_it; i++) if( e.value[i].search(/[\r\n]/) != -1 ) start_pos = start_pos - .5;
        stop_it = end_pos;
        for (i=0; i < stop_it; i++) if( e.value[i].search(/[\r\n]/) != -1 ) end_pos = end_pos - .5;

        tr.moveEnd('textedit',-1);
        tr.moveStart('character',start_pos);
        tr.moveEnd('character',end_pos - start_pos);
        tr.select();
    }
    return get_selection(the_id);
}

function wrap_selection(the_id, left_str, right_str, sel_offset, sel_length)
{
    var the_sel_text = get_selection(the_id).text;
    var selection =  replace_selection(the_id, left_str + the_sel_text + right_str );
    if(sel_offset !== undefined && sel_length !== undefined) selection = set_selection(the_id, selection.start +  sel_offset, selection.start +  sel_offset + sel_length);
    else if(the_sel_text == '') selection = set_selection(the_id, selection.start + left_str.length, selection.start + left_str.length);
    return selection;
}
```

Comment: Of all the solutions I've seen for this problem, this is the only one that's been working for me.

Comment: you should take the elements as parameters instead of the IDs, that makes it a lot more flexible. Otherwise brilliant! Thank you very much for an insight other people/websites failed to provide.

Comment: Nice functions; they were easy to adapt to my needs. There is one bug though which will catch out IE 6 & 7. In the set_selection function you have "e.value[i]". This should be changed to "e.value.charAt(i)". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx

Comment: In `wrap_selection()` add `left_str=left_str||'';right_str=right_str||'';` and you can do a simple insert with just passing in a value for `left_str` - like `<br />` or `&bull; ` (without these to set default, if you pass just a value for `left_str` the missing argument for `right_str` produces "undefined")

Answer (score 6):

I've just adopted the solution presented by user357565, and recoded for jQuery direct use:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.get_selection = function () {
    var e = this.get(0);
    //Mozilla and DOM 3.0
    if('selectionStart' in e) {
      var l = e.selectionEnd - e.selectionStart;
      return { start: e.selectionStart, end: e.selectionEnd, length: l, text: e.value.substr(e.selectionStart, l) };
    }
    else if(document.selection) {    //IE
      e.focus();
      var r = document.selection.createRange();
      var tr = e.createTextRange();
      var tr2 = tr.duplicate();
      tr2.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
      tr.setEndPoint('EndToStart',tr2);
      if (r == null || tr == null) return { start: e.value.length, end: e.value.length, length: 0, text: '' };
      var text_part = r.text.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.'); //for some reason IE doesn't always count the \n and \r in length
      var text_whole = e.value.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.');
      var the_start = text_whole.indexOf(text_part,tr.text.length);
      return { start: the_start, end: the_start + text_part.length, length: text_part.length, text: r.text };
    }
    //Browser not supported
    else return { start: e.value.length, end: e.value.length, length: 0, text: '' };
  };

  $.fn.set_selection = function (start_pos,end_pos) {
    var e = this.get(0);
    //Mozilla and DOM 3.0
    if('selectionStart' in e) {
      e.focus();
      e.selectionStart = start_pos;
      e.selectionEnd = end_pos;
    }
    else if (document.selection) { //IE
      e.focus();
      var tr = e.createTextRange();

      //Fix IE from counting the newline characters as two seperate characters
      var stop_it = start_pos;
      for (i=0; i < stop_it; i++) if( e.value[i].search(/[\r\n]/) != -1 ) start_pos = start_pos - .5;
      stop_it = end_pos;
      for (i=0; i < stop_it; i++) if( e.value[i].search(/[\r\n]/) != -1 ) end_pos = end_pos - .5;

      tr.moveEnd('textedit',-1);
      tr.moveStart('character',start_pos);
      tr.moveEnd('character',end_pos - start_pos);
      tr.select();
    }
    return this.get_selection();
  };

  $.fn.replace_selection = function (replace_str) {
    var e = this.get(0);
    selection = this.get_selection();
    var start_pos = selection.start;
    var end_pos = start_pos + replace_str.length;
    e.value = e.value.substr(0, start_pos) + replace_str + e.value.substr(selection.end, e.value.length);
    this.set_selection(start_pos,end_pos);
    return {start: start_pos, end: end_pos, length: replace_str.length, text: replace_str};
  };

  $.fn.wrap_selection = function (left_str, right_str, sel_offset, sel_length) {
    var the_sel_text = this.get_selection().text;
    var selection =  this.replace_selection(left_str + the_sel_text + right_str );
    if(sel_offset !== undefined && sel_length !== undefined) 
      selection = this.set_selection(selection.start +  sel_offset, selection.start +  sel_offset + sel_length);
    else if(the_sel_text == '') 
      selection = this.set_selection(selection.start + left_str.length, selection.start + left_str.length);
    return selection;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

I hope someone finds it useful!

Comment: Thanks man! used your code and modified it some to account for toggle wrapper etc. You want me to include note/link to you?

Comment: Thanks but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

the only thing i can add is that it seem (didn't acually try it) that this should scroll all the way up whenever you manpulate the content. an eay remedy is to wrap the line that does

```
e.value =
```

with two lines to copy and restore scrollTop, like so:

```
var rememberScrollTop = e.scrollTop;
e.value = .... (same as in user357565 snippet)
e.scrollTop = rememberScrollTop;
```