# How can I get the selected text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my own [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor. Is there a way to get the text which has the user selected in a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)?

For example, if the user selects some word and then clicks button, how do I find out which text was selected?

I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401593/javascript-textarea-selection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the jquery-fieldselection plugin.

You can download it from [here](http://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection/tree/master). There is an example too.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: The function `replaceSelection` from that plugin does not work for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 91):

[`window.getSelection().toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) worked for me with Chrome, but [not Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686).

For obtaining the selected content in a `<textarea>` with Firefox:

```
function getSel() // JavaScript
{
    // Obtain the object reference for the <textarea>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");

    // Obtain the index of the first selected character
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;

    // Obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;

    // Obtain the selected text
    var sel = txtarea.value.substring(start, finish);


    // Do something with the selected content
}
```

You could also use [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) instead of [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Reference:

- *[textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)*
- *[document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument#Introduction)*

Comment: `window.getSelection().toString()` does exactly the same thing, and you don't need to know the id of the textarea. You can't have multiple selections in different text areas at the same time.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I've tried that before, and now. It works with Chrome, but does not seem to work with FireFox.

Comment: Correct - turns out [there is a Firefox bug filed in 2001](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686) about window.getSelection() not working in textareas!

Comment: Indeed, there's a bug in Firefox, which was filed back in 2001 (!). I've mentioned that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript/32397146#32397146).

Answer (score 18):

Handling selection is different for different browsers:

```
var userSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    userSelection = window.getSelection();
}
else if (document.selection) { // Opera
    userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
}
```

That gives you a range object. Each range represents a single selection (using control/command key it's possible to make multiple active selections).

The type of range object you have now depends on what browser. For IE it's a Text Range object; for others its a Selection object. To convert a Selection object into a text range, you can call getRangeAt; for Safari, you need to build that:

```
var range;
if (userSelection.getRangeAt)
    range = userSelection.getRangeAt(0);
else { // Safari
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(userSelection .anchorNode, userSelection.anchorOffset);
    range.setEnd(userSelection.focusNode, userSelection.focusOffset);
}
```

The range object provides you with the starting and ending dom elements and text offset of the selection.

More information about range objects can be found at [quirksmode.org here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html)

If you are using jQuery, you may want to look at the [light weight jQuery RTE Plugin](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html) by Batiste Bieler. It may do enough for your needs or at least give you something to start with.

Comment: Very useful and informative answer.

Comment: It may be time for [an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194113/how-to-get-range-of-selected-text-of-textarea-in-javascript/41233895#41233895).

Answer (score 10):

getSelection()

This varies a bit by browser. See here for a function that alleges to work in most:
http://snipplr.com/view/775/getselection/

Comment: How do you use this function on a specific `textarea` element ?

Comment: The above code doesn't work in Firefox browser (61.0.1) @tpdi

Comment: Does the link work? It redirects to a login page (for most people).

Answer (score 10):

A small function that will get the selected string/text of a *[textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)* or an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) element:

```
function getInputSelection(elem){
  if(typeof elem != "undefined"){
    s = elem[0].selectionStart;
    e = elem[0].selectionEnd;
    return elem.val().substring(s, e);
  }
  else{
    return '';
  }
}
```

Note that the above code needs [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) for working. An example of getting the selected string of an input element with id **abc123** is:

```
getInputSelection($("#abc123"));
```

The above function will return the selected string. If there isn’t any string that is selected by the user, it will return `null`.

### More Examples

```
getInputSelection($("body").find("input[name=user]"));
```

On elements selected with class name, the selected string of the first element of the array of elements is returned and not the selected string of all the elements. After all, selection in a page will always be **1**.

Comment: Please show an example.

Comment: I like the ability to pass any element into your function, it makes it much more portable/reusable.

Answer (score -4):

```
function getSel() {
    var input = $("#text");
    return input.html().toString().substring(getSelection().baseOffset, getSelection().extendOffset);
}
```

Comment: This code is not correct. Indeed its giving me whole text of textarea instead of selected text.

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers