# Storing Highlighted text in a variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript function that will allow me to capture the text that is currently highlighted with the cursor and store it in a variable? I've been trying document.selection.createRange().text but this hasn't been working. Are there any possible alternatives? Here's the code:

```
function moremagic(){
var output = document.selection.createRange();
alert("I Work!");}
```

When I run the function, it doesn't make it to the write statement so I know something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ungraciously stolen [from another question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815202/insert-selected-text-on-the-page-into-textarea-jquery)

```
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Use this in a "onClick" function or whatever and it will return the selected text in almost any browser.

Comment: `window.getSelection()` will return a `Selection` object, not a string.

Comment: The way I read it, it's just for checking the return value for a browser check.  One works in "all" browsers, the other works in IE ;)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. You're correct that it's checking for the existence of objects/functions before using them. The issue is that this function will return a `Selection` object in non-IE browsers and a string in IE. You need to call `toString()` on the `Selection` before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you want [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.getSelection).

Comment: Oops, I forgot IE implements “document.selection” instead. So if you want cross-browser code, you need to branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return "" + window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return "";
}
```