# How can I highlight every single word in jquery so that I can provide a definition for each word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highlighting

What I am trying to do is allow the user to scroll over any word on a web page and when the mouse goes over the word it is highlighted (I know I can use hover for that).  However I do not know how to select individual words, from the paragraph.  The ultimate goal is to allow the user to click on the word and a definition appears over the word, but I think I can figure that out once I can hover over individual words.

Comment: --EVERY-- word on the page? Is the page big? I can see a slow DOM on the horizon.

Comment: no the page is relatively small, just a couple of paragraphs.

I was just seeing if it was possible, so thanks dean for answering my question.  And yes, I find the hover popup things very annoying as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Javascript to do that, the smallest thing you can interact with, in general, is a DOM element. So you could technically wrap each word inside a `<span>`, but that would seem to be seriously overkill and probably have a huge performance impact as well.

Instead, what most sites do, that provide this functionality, is they do the hover popup thing whenever you select text ([see this question for some code to get the current selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815202/insert-selected-text-on-the-page-into-textarea-jquery/815236#815236)).

Personally, I find it really irritating (nytimes.com does it like that, for example), but maybe that's just me...

Comment: Yes, this would probably be the best way to do it. Another resource is the NYTimes's script which luckily isn't minified or obfuscated: http://graphics8.nytimes.com/js/common/screen/altClickToSearch.js

Answer (score 1):

If you want something similar to what the NYtimes provides, I suggest that you use the Select Link plugin in JQuery, which provides a search for any word that is selected in your text. Confer [this link](http://preprocess.me/codes/selectlink/index.html).

Comment: _Page not found. The requested page could not be found._