# Get a word when mouse is over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I develop chrome extension and I need to get a word of any web page when mouse is over this word. 
I don't want to put all words to specific containers and then get it by id.
For example, if I have `<p>The weather is very good today</p>` I want to make mouse over the word "very" and get it in my js (for example, `alert('very')`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I highlight every single word in jquery so that I can provide a definition for each word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445151/how-can-i-highlight-every-single-word-in-jquery-so-that-i-can-provide-a-definiti)

Comment: ^ basically the same question as here.

Comment: not the same, that question about javascript only but I use chrome api

Comment: @Ukrainianguy Are you saying you don't want to put a span around the matching text? If so, you're out of luck, you can't interact with parts of a text node. You'd have to wrap your words with tags. The only other solution is selection based, as suggested in Neal's comment

Comment: @Juan Mendes, unfortunately my boss doesn't know the word "can't", especially when there are chrome apps with such opportunity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to show you a **[proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/X6jvb/)** for this feature. It's very naive and weak but shows that it's possible with an appropriate regex. Basically, hover the green-bordered div to see the results.

With this approach, each paragraph is split into spanned chunks with a regex. The more powerful regex, the better result, of course. Then, `onmousemove` is bubbling, being triggered by a span. Reading a content of the span is a piece of cake.

This method is very intrusive, by modifying DOM structure, which you probably don't want to touch. It works in plain JS though. The more advanced (still easy) approach would be as follows:

1. Don't touch any paragraph.
2. Observe `onmousemove` to find the paragraph under the mouse.
3. Save `clientX` and `clientY`.
4. Copy the paragraph, make it transparent and `position: absolute`.
5. Do the `spanify()` thing on **a copy**.
6. Use [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) to find which span is being hovered. Use saved (3.) `clientX` and `clientY` shifted by the position of the copy (left, top).
7. You've got the span. You've got its content.
8. Remove paragraph copy from DOM.

This hack still works in plain JS. Happy coding! ;)

Comment: Very nice! But it does create a bunch of spans, which I thought was not what the OP wanted

Comment: Yeah. This is the only way to have it in pure JS though.

Comment: Thank you, @oleq! This is the best solution yet.