# JQuery, Filter by User Selection? Range?

Tags: jquery, html, filter

How can I filter my selector by what the user has selected???

I'm trying to find specific elements inside what the user has highlighted.

```
$('.item', document.selection) ?
$('.item', editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0]) ?
```

Comment: by selector you mean select dropdown?

Comment: no i mean literally what the user has highlighted on the page.

Comment: For instance, if I highlighted your comment "by selector you mean select dropdown?" and wanted to look for bold or paragraph elements inside that highlighted selection, how would i do that?

Comment: This sounds more like a web-browser plugin. Firefox offers this sort of functionality with their FireBug plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Insert selected text on the page into textarea (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815202/insert-selected-text-on-the-page-into-textarea-jquery/815236#815236)

This might help. Maybe push it into a hidden element and then have jQuery reference that

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it will give you the text a user has selected (highlighted) on a page. However, this will not get the DOM structure, but merely the text.