# JQuery.select() for <div>

Tags: jquery

http://api.jquery.com/select/ mentions that $().select()

> "The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a **text selection** inside it. This event is **limited** to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes."

I am trying to detect text selection in `<div>`.

What's the best way to provide the equilvalent $().select()?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar [Q&A is posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815202/insert-selected-text-on-the-page-into-textarea-jquery). You could use that function to get selected text in a div bound to the `mouseup` javascript event.

E.g.

```
$('#div').mouseup(function() {
  alert(getSelectedText());
});

// Get user selection text on page
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code in my pages:

```
if (document.selection)
 {
     text = document.selection.createRange().text;
 }

else if (document.getSelection)
 {
     text = document.getSelection();
 }

else if (window.getSelection)
 {
     text = window.getSelection();
 }
else return;
```

It has some problems with newer versions of IE but other than that it's pretty good.