# Need to make selected text as bold/italic/underline using javascript, and also save & retrieve the same using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, bold

I need to make selected text of textbox bold/italic/underline using javascript. For that i am using the following code.

```
<img src="~/images/Bold"  alt="Bold" onclick="changeFont('TextBox1','b');"  />
<img src="~/images/Italic" alt="Italic" onclick="changeFont('TextBox1','i');"  />
<img src="~/images/Underline" alt="Underline" onclick="changeFont('TextBox1','u');"  />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function changeFont(txt, change) {
        if (change == 'b') {
            if (document.getElementById(txt).style.fontWeight == 'bold')
                document.getElementById(txt).style.fontWeight = 'normal';
            else
                document.getElementById(txt).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        }
        else if (change == 'i') {
            if (document.getElementById(txt).style.fontStyle == 'italic')
                document.getElementById(txt).style.fontStyle = 'normal';
            else
                document.getElementById(txt).style.fontStyle = 'italic';
        }
        else {
            if (document.getElementById(txt).style.textDecoration == 'underline')
                document.getElementById(txt).style.textDecoration = 'none';
            else
                document.getElementById(txt).style.textDecoration = 'underline';
        }
    }
</script>
```

But the issue here is, when i click on bold image its making the whole text into bold but not the selected text. It´s not working for the other two images either.

While saving the text of textbox I am unable to get the text including html tags even after trying with

```
document.getElementById('TextBox1').innerHTML;
```

I am able to get only the value of textbox.

Is there any way to save and retrieve the same using javascript or C#

Thanks in advance
SC

Comment: I just stumbled upon this thread and wanted to let you guys know that [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a question that answers your problem about getting the highlighting text 
[How to get selected text in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea)

About making the selected text bold you would need to use html tags or something like bbcode and parse it to html when you print it on to a page.

EDIT: [Here is a page that shows the jquery plugin "fieldselection" in action.](http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.2.3-test/test.html)

EDIT 2: Here is an example of how I would've done this: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KscJk/9/)

**The HTML:**

```
<input id="bold" type="button" value="B" />
<br />
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>

<div id="resultAsHtml"></div>
<br />
<div id="resultAsText"></div>
```

**The javascript (jquery) code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#editor").keyup(Update);

    function Update(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        var result = ParseToHtml(text);
        $("#resultAsHtml").html(result);
        $("#resultAsText").text(result);
    }

    $("#bold").click(function(){
        var range = $("#editor").getSelection();
        var textToReplaceWith = "[b]"+ range.text + "[/b]";
        $("#editor").replaceSelection(textToReplaceWith , true);

        var text = $("#editor").val();
        var result = ParseToHtml(text);
        $("#resultAsHtml").html(result);
        $("#resultAsText").text(result);
    });

    function ParseToHtml(text) {
        text = text.replace("[b]", "<b>");
        text = text.replace("[/b]", "</b>");
        text = text.replace("  ","&nbsp;");
        text = text.replace("\n","</br>");
        return text;
    }

    $("#bold").replaceSelection("[b]" + $("#editor").getSelection() + "[/b]", true);
});
```

Comment: Hi Joakim, Thanks for teh reply. But I'm unable to get the selected text. As soon as i click on Bold image, the selected text getting unselected. 
Could you please help me.

Comment: See the link I added to my answer, which displays how you can use the jquery plugin refered to in the first link in my answer.

Comment: Hi Joakim,
with the link they have provided, I cpould only get the selected text, but i can't format(make it bold) and put bak in the same text box. If its not possible with textbox, is there any other control in which i can format the text. Please advise.

Comment: Updated my answer once again with an example of how you could do it.

Answer (score 1):

document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
this is Simplest techinique which worked for me 
in all browsers ...