# How to get the selected text in a textrarea using raw JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get selected text in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea)

Are there any cross browser way to get just the selected text in a textarea? By selected I mean the usual, when user clicks mouse down and drags over some text and the text is highlighted to indicate selection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [jquery-fieldselection](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection) that does this.