# .getSelection()

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code--

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.field.selection.js"></script>

    <div id="copy">Copy</div>
        <textarea....id="t">
```

jquery---

```
$(docu.....
$('#copy').click(function(){
var range = $('#TextArea').getSelection();
alert(range.text);
});

});
```

When the #copy button is pressed the alert does not show the selected text in #t.  It comes in blank.

I need the selected text from the textarea

Comment: It helps if you actually ask a question.

Comment: try console.log or .debug and see what gets returned

Comment: Whats the idea with -4 on the Q?

Comment: the question is extremely bad written. you aren't explaining what you've tried on you own, you don't say if any errors occur (and havn't posted the error-messages). your code is formatted badly and hard to read. anyway, i havn't downvoted this, but only because i have no votes left for today.

Comment: @oezi can you tell me what this sentence means - When the #copy button is pressed the alert does not show the selected text in #t. It comes in blank.

Comment: @oezi can you tell me what this sentence means - I need the selected text from the textarea

Answer (score 1):

`getSelection` is a method of the document, so you should do:

```
var range = document.getSelection();
```

also note that you'll have to use `document.selection.createRange()` in IE so everything gets a bit complicated.
take a look at [this example](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-138944.html) for more information. you'll end up needing a function like this:

```
function getSelectedText(){
  if(document.all){
    var selection = document.selection;
    var newRng = selection.createRange();
    newRng.select();
    return newRng.htmlText;
  }else{
    return document.getSelection();
  }
}
```

wich should return the selected text and work in all major browsers.

**EDIT:**
just saw you're using some kind of jquery-plugin that (maybe) should make your code work. the problem is:

in your html, the id of the textarea is "t":

```
<textarea....id="t">
```

but in your javascript, you're trying to get the selection of id "TextArea":

```
$('#TextArea').getSelection();
```

please change the id of your textarea to "TextArea" (or the other way around) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not running because, this statement fails

```
var range = $('#TextArea').getSelection();
```

There is nothing as `TextArea` as ID in the markup you provided, so the script encounters an error and does not continue beyond it.

If you place the alert at the top part, I am sure the alert box will pop up.
i.e

```
$('#copy').click(function(){
    alert(''); //this will work
    var range = $('#TextArea').getSelection();
    alert(range.text);
});
```

Comment: Did that, am getting the range.text blank (no value returned), but start point, end point all are returned

Comment: @Jean, can you first show me where is `#Textarea` in your code... are you trying to refer to the textarea element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the question, but if you need to get the textarea value, just use the `val` jQuery method:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('#copy').click(function(){
  var range = $('#t').val();
  alert(range);
});
```

Comment: I need the selected text from the textarea

Comment: Then google it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea

Comment: I did and got the plugin jquery.field.selection.js, and read everything in it, but the range.text is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Either you change your `id="t"` or you change `#TextArea` to `#t` to get the textarea you have in your html markup.

But I have no idea what plugin that you are using or what it want.