# Javascript check if text selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a simple function (javascript / jquery) that checks whether or not ANY contents of a textarea is selected or highlighted... the function needs to return true or false.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get selected text in textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea)

Comment: ^^ Google however, seems to do a good job answering ["check whether text selected in textarea".](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=check+whether+text+selected+in+textarea&pbx=1&oq=check+whether+text+selected+in+textarea)

Comment: try http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this

```
function isTextSelected(input){
   var startPos = input.selectionStart;
   var endPos = input.selectionEnd;
   var doc = document.selection;

   if(doc && doc.createRange().text.length != 0){
      return true;
   }else if (!doc && input.value.substring(startPos,endPos).length != 0){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Usage

```
if(isTextSelected($('#textareaId')[0])){
   //text selected
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qDvYt/)**

Comment: if even unselect the text, it will continue returning selected!

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior as stated by @thatsalok. I'll look for a solution, though

Comment: @thatsalok - Because of the alert the text loses focus but stays selected. It does not look like it, but it is true. In the demo try to add this line after the alert $('#textareaId')[0].focus(); You will see your selection again.

You can loose your selection, by making a selection of 0 characters ( in other words placing the cursor somewhere in the text area ).

I made a fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/qDvYt/184/

Comment: @ShankarSangoli As of 2019, you can use latest one https://codepen.io/faizanrupani/pen/ZVwGyV