# jQuery bind on click when not highlighting

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to react to a click only when the user is **not** highlighting the text like facebook does in its chat windows?

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", '.content', $.proxy(function(e) {
// if ($(e.currentTarget).isHighlighted()) return false;
}, this));
```

Comment: Is this a similar question for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065828/javascript-check-if-text-selected

Comment: This is not really working well. See the comment on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insider your `click` handler, you can test to see if the document has any [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection):

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", function() {
    if(!document.getSelection().toString().length) {
        console.log("No selection made");
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bud6x/) of the above.

If you need it to work in IE8, you'll need to use `document.selection` instead.

Comment: @Chris Everything but <=IE8. You'd need to use `document.selection` for that instead

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

You can use [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), and take care of cross-browser compatibility.

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", '.content', $.proxy(function(e) {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection && selection.containsNode(e.target)) {//selection contains event target
    return false;
  }
}, this));
```

To be more accurate, you can check whether `focusNode` or `anchorNode` is the event target.