# Not allow initial spaces on input

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to deny initial spaces on my input (which is not in a form), I have code like this:

```
<input id="customer-name" class="required no-spaces" minlength="3"  />
```

And this is my javascript function:

```
$(".no-spaces").on('keypress', function(e) {
     if (e.which == 32) {
         return false;
     }
});
```

But this doesn't allow spaces in any part of the input. How to do it just before any text?

**Edit:** The real is that I'm doing an autocomplete with the input and, If i allow initial spaces it will return all data.

Comment: `if (this.value == "" && e.which == 32) e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Why don't you just remove initial spaces when processing the input?

Comment: Because i'm doing an autocomplete with the input.

Comment: So remove the space, then complete it.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if the string is empty beforehand.

```
$(".no-spaces").on('keypress', function(e) {
     if ($(this).val() == "" && e.which == 32) {
         return false;
     }
});
```

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065828/javascript-check-if-text-selected) in order to prevent the case where the user selects the entire text and then presses space and [this](http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/) to check if the cursor is indeed at the beggining of the input (Thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for mentioning this specific case)

Comment: Much better more efficient than the other two which will trim or evaluate a regex every time a space is pressed. +1

Comment: This won't stop them from moving the cursor to the beginning of a non-empty input and inserting a space.

Comment: Added the reference to input.js, which will help him cover this case as well. Thanks @Barmar

Comment: @Sam: How is that "better"? It just does less…

Answer (score 1):

Just simply check there is another character on textbox.

```
$(".no-spaces").on('keypress', function(e) {
     if (e.which == 32 && ($this).val() == '') {
         return false;
     }
});
```

**Edit**

I hope it might be work.

```
$(".no-spaces").on('keypress', function(e) {
     $(this).val(function(i, v) {
        if (v[0] == ' ') {
            return v.slice(1, v.length);
        };
        return v;
     });
});
```

Comment: Since this is the same as William Barbosa's answer, my comment there applies.

Comment: I like your edit, but I think you'll still be able to copy/paste multiple spaces..I think you may want to make this recursively check `v[0]` and removing spaces until there isn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".no-spaces").on('keypress', function(e) {
     if (e.which == 32) {
         $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\W*/, ''));
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$(".no-spaces").on('keypress', function(e) {
     var val = $(this).val();
     val_ltrim = ltrim(val);
     $(this).val(val_ltrim);
});
```

Greetings.