# How can I detect click is hold but not moved?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
doc.on('mousedown', '.qandacontent', function() {
    timeout_id = setTimeout(menu_toggle.bind(this), 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```

This will show a pop up if you click on element `.qandacontent` and hold it for 1 sec. Now I want to make it working only if no text is selected (marked) while click-holding. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a runnable snippet if you can. Or add the html so that the people who reply could provide a snippet closely matching your problem statement

Answer (score 0):

You could check if there is selected text, and if so, where it is :

```
if ($(window.getSelection().anchorNode).attr('id') === 'something') { ... }
```

See:

- [How to check if text is highlighted (cross-browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331302/how-to-check-if-text-is-highlighted-cross-browser?rq=1)
- [Javascript check if text selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065828/javascript-check-if-text-selected)