# Is there any alternative method for isTextSelected() in jquery or javascript.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative method for the [following code](http://www.scratchinginfo.net/how-to-find-out-if-the-text-in-a-textbox-is-selected-with-jquery/) in jquery or javascript.?

```js
function isTextSelected(input) {
  if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number") {
    return input.selectionStart == 0 && input.selectionEnd == input.value.length;
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    input.focus();
    return document.selection.createRange().text == input.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="text_selected" type="text" value="Select Text" />
<input onmousedown="console.log(isTextSelected(document.getElementById('text_selected')));" type="button" value="Selected or Not" />
```

Comment: What's the original `isTextSelected()` method?

Comment: isTextSelected(id) returns boolean value, if text is selected in textbox.

[link]http://www.scratchinginfo.net/how-to-find-out-if-the-text-in-a-textbox-is-selected-with-jquery/

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: I am trying to pass Id as an argument, but its coming as null, the project is very old in vb.net and I have to make it work in IE6

Comment: So change to `function isTextSelected(ID) { var input = document.getElementById(ID); ...`

Comment: If you just need to see if it is empty or changed: `var field = document.getElementById('text_selected'); if (field.value=="" || field.value==field.defaultValue) alert("empty or not changed"); `

Comment: It worked :) Thank You @mplungjan

Comment: Great - I converted the comment to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to see if it is empty or changed:

```
var field = document.getElementById('text_selected'); 
if (field.value=="" || field.value==field.defaultValue) {
  alert("empty or not changed");
}
```

You can add trim:

```
if (field.value.trim()==""
```

Or using jQuery:

```
if ($.trim(field.value)==""
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure where you get the `isTextSelected()` method but perhaps you should look into `Window.getSelection()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Perhaps this will help too: [How to get selected html text with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643635/how-to-get-selected-html-text-with-javascript)

Comment: [link]http://www.scratchinginfo.net/how-to-find-out-if-the-text-in-a-textbox-is-selected-with-jquery/

Comment: So it's just a function, can't you refactor or just use this?

Comment: FYI: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065828/javascript-check-if-text-selected

Answer (score 0):

if you mean get selected text from drop down list you can use this :

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

Comment: No, not from dropdown, textbox instead.

Comment: so use : $('#textboxid').val()

Comment: I dont want the value, i just want to check if it is blank or not, or if the value has changed.

Comment: if($('#textboxid').val() == ""){//here ur code work when the input is empty}