# Double click words in the input selects extra space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple input with the text inside:

```js
document.querySelector('.input').value = 'Double click on words without extra space'
```

```css
.input {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="">
```

Except the last word in the input if you double-click any other words it will be selected with an extra space afterwards.

Is there any solution so that double-clicking any word in the input only select the whole word without that space?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/282568/is-there-a-way-to-not-select-whitespace-after-a-word-when-double-clicking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In browsers: Select only the selected word, not with the space after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154753/in-browsers-select-only-the-selected-word-not-with-the-space-after-it) Please search around before asking a question that has been asked multiple times already

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the text selection using [`Selection#modify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify) with parameters `alter: "extend"`, `direction: "left"` and `granularity: "character"`.

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify):

> The Selection.modify() method applies a change to the current selection or cursor position, using simple textual commands.

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('.input');
inputElement.value = 'Double click on words without extra space';

inputElement.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const text = selection.toString();

  if (/\s+$/.test(text)) { // Check if there is a trailing whitespace
    selection.modify("extend", "left", "character");
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="">
```