# How to get range of selected text of textarea in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am trying to retrieve/find the start point and end point of selection in textarea.

Here is my code which work fine in [Mozilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) and chrome, but it is not working in [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9):

```html
<script type="txt/javascript">
    function update(o) {

        var t = o.value, s = getSelectionStart(o), e = getSelectionEnd(o);
        alert("start: " + s + " End: " + e);
    }

    function getSelectionStart(o) {
        if (o.createTextRange) {
            var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
            rse = r.text.length;
            r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
            if (r.text == '')
                return o.value.length
            return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
        }
        else
            return o.selectionStart
    }

    function getSelectionEnd(o) {
        if (o.createTextRange) {
            var r = document.selection.createRang;
            e().duplicate()
            r.moveStart('character', -o.value.length)
            return r.text.length
        }
        else
            return o.selectionEnd
    }
</script>

<textarea id ="text" rows=10 cols="50" onselect="update(this);"></textarea>
```

When I test this code in Mozilla and Chrome, it gives me correct answer, but when I run this code in Internet Explorer 9, it shows -1 for start and any value for end.

I want to just find out the start and end point/index of the selected text of the textarea. Actually, the above code works fine for a textbox in all browsers, but not with textarea.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably missing doctype declaration or missing `X-UA Compatible`, or both. Though `getSelectionEnd()` won't work in any browser, there's a typo, maybe just in the post only?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the code below or check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSX52/)

```
   function getTextSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    alert("start :" + start + " End :" + end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help its working fine in chrome, mozila but In IE9 it shows me end value wrong. Start value showing correct but end value is not could you please check again...

Comment: Sorry for not double checking the code. Couldn't get your example to work so I found the answer elsewhere. I hope this helps you (I edited the previous code).

Comment: Thanks yaar its working thanku very much you are genius.. It showing me perfect ans in every browser.

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this not only in <textarea> but in various elements such as <p> ? Thanks

Comment: Be aware that this works in IE <9, not in modern browsers.

Answer (score 7):

While the original answer may have helped the OP in 2012, things have changed, and this has now become simpler, at least in modern browsers.

---

You can use the JavaScript `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` attributes of the textarea.

#### Basic Usage

These are both standard attributes that will work in today's major browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Edge, and IE).

For example:

```js
console.log(
    document.getElementById("text").selectionStart,
    document.getElementById("text").selectionEnd
)
```

will show both the start and end point of the selection in the textarea with the ID `text`.

#### Boundary Cases

If there is no item selected in the textarea, then both the start and end attributes will return the last position of the [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)#Text_cursor). If the textarea has not received focus yet, the attributes will both return a value of `0`.

#### Changing the Selection

By setting these attributes to new values, you will adjust the active text selection. Thus, you can also use this to select text in a textarea.

#### Checking if a selection is in place

You can check if there is currently a selection by checking if the values are both different, i.e. if

```js
document.getElementById("text").selectionStart != document.getElementById("text").selectionEnd
```

is `true`, then there is a text selection.

#### Demo

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("text");
const selStart = document.getElementById("selStart");
const selEnd = document.getElementById("selEnd");

// should maybe also look at other events, e.g. "keydown", "select", etc
textarea.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  selStart.innerText = textarea.selectionStart;
  selEnd.innerText = textarea.selectionEnd;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text">Some text here</textarea>

<p>Selection Start: <span id="selStart">0</span></p>
<p>Selection End: <span id="selEnd">0</span></p>
```

#### References

- [Live Demo (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/040pdkpa/1/)
- [Documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement)
- [Documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974768(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This is a better, more modern answer for modern browsers