# HTML and JavaScript selecting a single textarea line

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write code that selects a single line of a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) input. The goal of the site is to provide an input for the user (the textarea) onto which he pastes a log file, and then I want to sort trough the data.

So I've got a textarea and a button below in HTML and don't know what to do from here on...I know the exact line I want to get, but the text length varies from log to log.

Is there a simple JavaScript and HTML solution for this? The select() method supposedly selects the whole content field.

Comment: this would be a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring

Comment: and this is the other part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650534/how-to-select-line-of-text-in-textarea

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ztLh8x6n/8/
See consol output...

Comment: You can use `textarea.value.split('\n')` to split it into an array of lines. Then you can index the array to get to the line you want.

Comment: @Barmar You can't do that in all cases, because textarea automatically warp word in new lines, without putting `\n` character.

Comment: @MatjažMav He's talking about a pasted log file, so I assume he wants the original lines from the file, not the displayed lines.

Comment: In this case will work :)

Comment: Related: *[How to get range of selected text of textarea in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194113/how-to-get-range-of-selected-text-of-textarea-in-javascript/41233895#41233895)*