# What is the purpose of document.selection.createRange().duplicate() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an old JavaScript code in my project and createRange() is undefined for internet explorer 11.

I replaced this part with getSelection() function.

Now, I can’t use getSelection with duplicate. What is the purpose of the duplicate function here?

document.selection.createRange().duplicate();

What should I use instead of duplicate? I can’t find examples of this function usage.

What should I use instead of the code "document.selection.createRange().duplicate();" to make my code work in IE11

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194113/how-to-get-range-of-selected-text-of-textarea-in-javascript

Comment: **[Replaced functionalities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx)**. I guess `getSelection` acts as `createRange().duplicate()`

Comment: before using such methods you should take advantage of http://caniuse.com