# Assign shortcut keys to input button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<script>
$('#pasteButton').click( function() {

  // place code for this button
  // ctrl + v shortcut should work for this button
  // how?
  }

});

</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="pasteButton" value="Paste" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance. Similarly, I also need to cut / copy selected text from a textarea using buttons.

*update from comment section :
I have a text area where I select some text and if I click on pasteButton that selected text need to be pasted in my text area*

Comment: may be you should try `Artificial Intelligence`.

Comment: First of all remove extra `}` from click function.

Answer (score 7):

First you have to listen to the keydown event. If it is control+v then you can trigger your function
You can use the following code for that purpose:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="pasteButton" value="press me" id="pasteButton"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $(window).keydown(function(event) {
          if(event.ctrlKey && (event.which == 86 || event.which==118)) { 
              $('#pasteButton').trigger("click")
            event.preventDefault(); 
          }
        });
        $('#pasteButton').click( function(){
            alert("hello");
        });
```

[SAMPLE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/cjXtW/3/)

Comment: am sorry i think my question is not clear.
i want the same functionality of 'ctrl+v' on click of 'pasteButton'

Comment: @mbsr, If like that, what is your real requirement? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a text area where i select some text and if i click on pasteButton that selected text need to be pasted in my text area.

Comment: @mbsr, sorry for the late reply, so you need only copy functionality? Or you need 'ctrl+v' short cut too?

Comment: @mbsr, its little more complicated than you expect, refer these similar SO question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have seen these examples, 2nd one 1 used for selecting text but that selected text need to be pasted on click of button.

Comment: something like in gre exam while writing awa section we can find this.

Comment: how if you only use 1 shorcut key like f7 only.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this post:

[How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#pasteButton').click( function()
    {
        // Your click functionality here
    }

    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86;

    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
    }).keyup(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = false;
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == vKey) {
           // ctrl + V clicked, click the paste button.

           $('#pasteButton').click();
           return false;
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **accesskey** attribute of html tag for more detail see following link

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp