# How to delete selected text in textarea tag in HTML on pressing button?

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to delete or remove the user seleted text from textarea on button press in angular js.

example:

```
<textarea>My name is Bob</textarea>
```

so if user selects "name" from text area and presses a button so the new text become:

```
<textarea>My is Bob</textarea>
```

I am new to angular so kindly help me.
Thanks.

Comment: **[This might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this ..

```
<textArea id="txtArea"> </textArea>
var txt =  document.getElementById("txtArea"); 


txt.value.replace(txt.value.substring(txt.selectionStart,txt.selectionEnd),"");
```

```js
function showVal()
{
  
    var txt =  document.getElementById("txtArea");
   alert( txt.value.replace(txt.value.substring(txt.selectionStart,txt.selectionEnd),""));
 }
```

```html
<textArea id="txtArea"> </textArea>
<button  onclick="showVal()">ClickMe</button>
```

Comment: this not an angularjs solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to implement this. First give id to your text area

```
<textarea id="textarea">My name is Bob</textarea>
```

Now in your javascript, button click handler function do following

```
var ta = document.getElementById("textarea");
var start = ta.selectionStart;
var finish = ta.selectionEnd;
var text = ta.value.substring(0,start-1)+ta.value.substring(finish,ta.value.lenth-1);
ta.value = text;
```