# how to get the value of select() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have search a lot but google just return me how to get the selected value of a select element

```
$('#some_id').select(function() { 
    // how can i store the selected value in a variable.?
    alert('the selected value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event to get selected value. In the event handler you can use `$(this).val()` of `this.value` to get the selected value.

```
$('#some_id').change(function(){
  // how can i store the selected value in a variable.?
  v = this.value;

  alert('the selected value' + this.value);
});
```

Comment: i mean. when i highlight a text in a text box, textarea or where ever that is, but its selected using jquery with a select() "$('#id').select()" the highlighted or selected text can be used to evaluate or for any purpose i need to. am i clear sir.?

Comment: Are you looking to get selected text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.change()**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event. Something like this:

```
var current_value = 1;//can define any value null also
$('#some_id').change(function(){
    current_value = $(this).val();//storing
    alert(current_value);
});
```

> **Note:** if you want to store value in variable and use it anywhere else then you must define it globally like i did.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/smsLsb2L/)

Comment: i mean. when i highlight a text in a text box, textarea or where ever that is, but its selected using jquery with a select() "$('#id').select()" the highlighted or selected text can be used to evaluate or for any purpose i need to. am i clear sir.?

Comment: So you don't have `select` but you have `input` & `textarea` and you want highlighted text.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea it has all details

Comment: but its using DOM.? do they have any difference.?

Comment: Most jquery event uses `DOM`. You can use that if you want to get highlighted text.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
 $('#select_id').change(function(){
   var sval = $('#select_id').val();
   alert('the selected value' + sval);
});
```

Comment: i mean. when i highlight a text in a text box, textarea or where ever that is, but its selected using jquery with a select() "$('#id').select()" the highlighted or selected text can be used to evaluate or for any purpose i need to. am i clear sir.?