# Replace selected text from input fields on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I simply try to replace the selected text from an input field e.g from a textarea, with another text.
E.g. if i select a part of the text inside the input field and click the Button `CENTER`, then the selected text should be wrapped in `<center></center>`.

I found this "[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/717226/4684797)" from 2009 which seems to be outdated, I tried it with Chrome and Firefox and I get the info that my browser is not supported.

Is there another way to achieve this? It should work at least with Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Textarea]

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getSel() // javascript
{
console.log("test");

    // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    // obtain the index of the first selected character
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    // obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    //obtain all Text
    var allText = txtarea.value;

    // obtain the selected text
    var sel = allText.substring(start, finish);
    //append te text;
    var newText=allText.substring(0, start)+"<center>"+sel+"</center>"+allText.substring(finish, allText.length);

    console.log(newText);

    txtarea.value=newText;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qpw1eemr/1/

Comment: np! happy to help :)

Comment: also for a larger array of functions you can use ckeditor

Comment: this is awesome! cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here is one simple example

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').select(function(event) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var start = elem.prop("selectionStart");
    var end = elem.prop("selectionEnd");
    
    var prefixStr = elem.text().substring(0, start);
    var sufixStr = elem.text().substring(end, elem.text().length);
    var selectedStr = elem.text().substring(start, end);
    
    function transform(str) {
      return '<center>' + str + '</center>'
    }
    
    elem.text(prefixStr + transform(selectedStr) + sufixStr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // hope this would be usefull
    // i used these codes for auto completing the texts in textarea.
    // other methods change all matching items before the selected text
    // but this affects only the text where caret on.
    // at first, i divided textarea.value into 3 pieces. these are ;
    // p1; until the 'searched' item, p2 after 'searched' item
    // and pa = new item that will replaced with 'searched' item
    // then, i combined them together again.

    var tea = document.getElementById(targetTextArea);

    caretPosition = tea.selectionStart - ara.length; //ara=searched item
    p1 = tea.value.substring(0,caretPosition);
        console.log('p1 text : ' + p1);
    p2 = tea.value.substring(caretPosition+ara.length,tea.value.length);
        console.log('p2 text : ' + p2);
    pa = yeni;  //new item
        console.log('pa text : ' + pa);

    tea.value = p1 + pa + p2;

    tea.selectionStart = caretPosition + yeni.length;
    tea.selectionEnd = caretPosition + yeni.length;

    tea.focus();
```