# How to implement text selecting?

Tags: language-agnostic, text, selection

My question is not language based or OS based. I guess every system is offering some sort of TextOut(text, x, y) method. I am looking for some guidlines or articles how should I implement selection of outputed text. Could not find any info about this.

The only thing which comes to my mind is like this:

When user clicks some point on the text canvas I know the coordinates of this point. I need to calculate where exactly it will be in my text buffer. So I am traversing from the begining of the buffer and I am applying to each character (or block of text) a style (if it has any). After this, I know that after given style the letter has given size. I am adding its width and height to previously calculated X,Y coordinates. In this way, I am traversing the buffer until the calculated position has not reached the point that has been clicked by the user. After I reach the point within range of some offset I have starting point for the selection.

This is the basic idea. I don't know if this is good, I would like to know how this is done for real like for example in Firefox. I know I could browse the sources and if I won't have a choice I'll do it. But first I am trying to find some article about it...

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I'd recommend to look at open source code to see how others solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting text is inherently specific to the control which is containing it and the means it stores that text.

A very simple (though questionably inefficient means) is to run the text flow algorithm you are using when clicking on a point and stopping the algorithm when you have reached what is closest to that point.  More advanced controls might cache the text layout to make selections or drawing their content more efficient.  Depending on how much you value CPU time or memory there are ways to use caches and special cases to make this “hit test” cheaper.

If you can make any assertions (only one font in the control, so every line has the same height) then it is possible to make these tests cheaper by indexing the font layout by lines and then doing simple arithmetic to find out which line was clicked on.  If your text control is also using monospace fonts (every character occupies the same width as well as height) then you are in even more luck, as you can jump straight to the character information via a lookup table and two simple divisions.

Keep in mind that writing a text control from scratch is *obscenely difficult*.  For best practice, you should keep the content of the document separate from the display information.  The reason for this is because the text itself will need to be edited quite often, so algorithms such as Ropes or Gap Buffers may be employed on the data side to provide faster insertion around the caret.  Every time text is edited it must also be rendered, which involves taking that data and running it through some kind of formatting / flow algorithms to determine how it needs to be displayed to the user.  *Both of these sides require a lot of algorithms that may be annoying to get right.*

Unfortunately using the native TextOut functions will not help you.  You will need to use methods which give you the text extents for individual characters, and more advanced (multiline for example) controls often must do their own rendering of characters using this information.  Functions like TextOut are not built to deal with blinking insertion carets for example, or performing incremental updates on text layouts.  While some TextOut style functions may support word wrap and alignment for you, they also require re-rendering the entire string which becomes more undesirable in proportion to the amount of text you need to work with in your control.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking at a much lower level than necessary (not an insult. you are thinking that you need to do much more work then you need to). Most (if not all) languages with GUI support will also have some form of selectionRange that gives you either the string that was selected or the start and stop indices in the string.

With a modern language, you should never have to calculate pixels and character widths.

For text selection in Javascript, see this question: [Understanding what goes on with textarea selection with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401593/javascript-textarea-selection)

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) However I do need go to lower level. What if I want to implement my own textarea? This is exactly what I want to do, I want to implement an area where I could put the text with different formating and combine it with images. That's why I asked about the implementation details, cause I want to know how to do this by myself...

Comment: You won't likely find an article about how Browsers do it, as this is something only those hard-core people who are actually writing them think about.