# Detect selected text in a text area with javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

Is it possible to detect what text has been selected in a text area using Javascript?  I'm looking to show the user controls only when they have selected text

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401593/javascript-textarea-selection ?

Answer (score 2):

I've written a cross-browser function for getting the text selected in a textarea or text input and after some toing and froing the final version is I think the best one I've seen. I've posted it on Stack Overflow a few times before. Here's one example: [Is there an Internet Explorer approved substitute for selectionStart and selectionEnd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235411/is-there-an-internet-explorer-approved-substitute-for-selectionstart-and-selectio/4207763#4207763)

To detect when the user makes a selection in a textarea, you can use the `select` event:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("some_id");
textarea.onselect = function() {
    var selection = getInputSelection(textarea);
    var selectedText = textarea.value.slice(selection.start, selection.end);
    console.log("Selected text: " + selectedText);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It would be as simple as:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea")

textarea.addEventListener("select", () => {
  const selection = textarea.value.substring(
    textarea.selectionStart,
    textarea.selectionEnd
  )

  console.log('Your selection:', selection)
})
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement/select_event).