# Event similar to onSelect event? tinymce

Tags: javascript, events, tinymce

How can I trigger an event on text selection on tinymce? The onselect event does not work. Is there a specific event for this?

Do I have to use mouse down, mouse move and mouse up instead?

I have been searching all over for this but no event seems to exist that just triggers a selection on text.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps these links will help > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359451/detect-selected-text-in-a-text-area-with-javascript

Comment: yeah saw those but they don't work on tinyMCE. It has a separate selection which indicates the position of the caret on the document

Comment: They will work, if you correctly bind them to the iframe used by tineMCE...

Comment: oh yes you are right. I will look into that then if nothing specific is available. Thanks