# Detecting if textarea content is selected using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

We have a few text areas that have some text the user may copy to their clipboard.

Without going into too much detail as it will just complicate a straightforward question:

Is it possible to detect if a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)'s contents are 'selected'?

---

I should mention using the *onclick* (or other) event handlers are (ideally...) not an option.

As this text is selected by an 'outside of the textarea' action.

The flow is somewhat as follows:

Drop down choice is chosen -> Text in textarea is selected

*Or*

Textarea is clicked (onclick) -> Text in textarea is selected

I know we could use a whole bunch of event handlers to detect the state of the text in the textarea, but I was hoping there was a simpler way of doing by detecting the state of the text inside the textarea via JavaScript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401593/javascript-textarea-selection/403526#403526 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript). You'll need to adapt the code slightly, but it shows how to access the selection for both Mozilla and Internet Explorer browsers -

```
function ShowSelection()
{
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('Editor');
  var selectedText;
  // Internet Explorer version
  if (document.selection != undefined)
  {
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
  {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
  }
  alert("You selected: " + selectedText);
}
```

Comment: selected this answer because of the trident vs proper browser fork. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties hold the selection indexes.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
if(textarea.selectionStart == textarea.selectionEnd) alert("Nothing is selected!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [demo](http://labs.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.2.3-test/test.html). They use the [jQuery - fieldSelection](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection) plugin.

Comment: both are valid answers, but we dont use jquery :)