# jquery remove text selection range after pasteHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript snippet:

```
// IE < 9
r = document.selection.createRange();
r.collapse(true);
r.pasteHTML("<p> test html </p>");
```

This works but what I want is that once the HTML is pasted, it must lose the selection.

In other words, what happens is that after `pasteHtml` method executes, the text "test html" is selected on the page. I don't want this. I want text to be unselected but the cursor should be positioned at end of "test html" text.
I'm doing this in:

```
<div contenteditable="true"> </div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you doing this into a textarea?

Comment: I'm doing in a div. It has contenteditable="true".

Comment: What documentation have you looked at so far? What have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/403526/560648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: collapse the selected `TextRange` and reselect it:

```
var r = document.selection.createRange();
r.collapse(true);
r.pasteHTML("<p> test html </p>");

var selectedRange = document.selection.createRange();
selectedRange.collapse(false);
selectedRange.select();
```