# getSelection won't find selected text for me in custom text input

Tags: javascript, firebase, getselection, firepad

I'm using the new [**Firepad realtime text collaboration service**](http://www.firepad.io/#1).

I would like to use the JavaScript `getSelection` method on text in the box that the user selects.

However, my code isn't working for whatever reason.

My JavaScript:

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert(window.getSelection());
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Get Selected Text in Firepad</button>
```

[**My test site**](http://pad.irishhuddle.com/test.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the plug-in it seems FirePad is using a `textarea`.

According to [**another SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401593/understanding-what-goes-on-with-textarea-selection-with-javascript)'s answer it seems that `textareas` don't use the same selection ranges as other nodes.

The [**accepted answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/403526/448144) explains it like this:

> There is extra bizarreness going on with textarea nodes. If I remember
>   correctly they behave as any other nodes when you select them in IE,
>   but in other browsers they have an independent selection range which
>   is exposed via the .selectionEnd and .selectionStart properties on the
>   node.

The [**highest voted answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966703/448144) shows a solution.

The solution uses the reference to the `textarea` node directly and gets the selected range from there using the element's `selectionEnd` and `selectionStart` properties, similar to this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var e = document.getElementById('thearea');

    //Mozilla and DOM 3.0
    if ('selectionStart' in e) {
        var l = e.selectionEnd - e.selectionStart;

        var start = e.selectionStart,
            end = e.selectionEnd,
            length = l,
            text = e.value.substr(e.selectionStart, l);

        alert(text);
    }
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zbye/) - Using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` for `textarea`

---

I'm not sure if this is the same across all browsers these days but the above code and the additional information in the linked SO should hopefully help you in getting the desired result.

Comment: @musefan: Sorry, forgot to click save on the fiddle :) I fixed that now. Glad you noticed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firepad is based on CodeMirror. Rather than grabbing the selection directly from the DOM, you should use the functions that CodeMirror exposes to do this.

Check out getSelection() here:
http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the functions

```
firepad.getHtmlFromSelection();
firepad.insertTextAtCursor(textPieces);
firepad.getHtml();  
firepad.getText();
firepad.insertText(index,textPieces);
```