# Is there a highlight text event using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make the feature like in medium.com where when user highlight the text, it will pop up a modal?

So far I have no idea yet how to capture the highlight event with JavaScript. Any thought?

Comment: Refer to `Robert's` answer from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731328/on-text-highlight-event

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding what goes on with textarea selection with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401593/understanding-what-goes-on-with-textarea-selection-with-javascript)